# Which update method to override? in the mixin or the serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

While I am working on a project I find myself need to add some logic in the update of some entity in my model, but I don't know whether to add this logic in the update method in the UpdateModelMixin or the update method in the ModelSerializer. What is the difference between them?

I searched everywhere and didn't find any specific or general answer to that question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach it in two ways: either override the `update` method in the serializer or the `perform_update` method at the Viewset level. The choice depends on your specific use case.

If you need to include additional data during the update that is not part of the serializer fields, then you should override the `update` method within the serializer. On the other hand, if you need to perform some third-party API call after the update operation, it's better to override the `perform_update` method at the Viewset level.